# Curious about why the map.on(); is not working

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a backend with GET method and MySQL database and in my HTML file on my client-side, I write  to generate the map and add a few markers and lines on the map. Initially, I have the following code to start my map and markers:

```
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [12.550343, 55.665957],
        zoom: 2
    });
```

```
    async function getapi(url){
        const response = await fetch(url);
        var data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }
    getapi(api_url).then(data => {show(data);});
    function show(data){
        /*
        * This is the only function to manipulate with all airlines
        */
        for (r in data){
            dep_lat.push(data[r]['DepLat']);
            arr_lat.push(data[r]['ArrLat']);
            dep_lng.push(data[r]['DepLng']);
            arr_lng.push(data[r]['ArrLng']);
        }

        /*
        * Load all airlines on the map initially, without the point marker
        */
        map.on('load', function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < dep_lat.length; i++){
                //console.log("init map test");
                map.addSource('route'+String(i),{
                    'type': 'geojson',
                    'data': {
                        'type': 'Feature',
                        'properties': {},
                        'geometry': {
                            'type': 'LineString',
                            'coordinates': [
                                [dep_lng[i],dep_lat[i]],
                                [arr_lng[i],arr_lat[i]]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                });
                map.addLayer({
                    'id': 'route'+String(i),
                    'type': 'line',
                    'source': 'route'+String(i),
                    'layout': {
                        'line-join': 'round',
                        'line-cap': 'round'
                    },
                    'paint': {
                        'line-color': '#C0C',
                        'line-width': 3
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        for (var i = 0; i < dep_lat.length; i++){
            let deplng = dep_lng[i];
            let deplat = dep_lat[i];
            let arrlng = arr_lng[i];
            let arrlat = arr_lat[i];
            new ClickableMarker({color: 'red'})
                .setLngLat([deplng,deplat])
                .onClick(() => {
                    alert(show_route(deplng, deplat));
                })
                .addTo(map);
            new ClickableMarker({color: 'red'})
                .setLngLat([arrlng,arrlat])
                .onClick(() => {
                    alert(show_route(arrlng, arrlat));
                })
                .addTo(map);
        }
    }
```

And I have already written an extension for mapboxgl.Marker to deal with click event and it works fine, (attached extended class):

```
    class ClickableMarker extends mapboxgl.Marker{
        onClick(handleClick){
            this._handleClick = handleClick;
            return this;
        }
        _onMapClick(e){
            const targetElement = e.originalEvent.target;
            const element = this._element;
            if (this._handleClick && (targetElement===element || element.contains((targetElement)))){
                this._handleClick();
            }
        }
    };
```

However, in the show_route() function, which is called in onClick(), I have the following code and I only get the second console log, the "Testing" inside map.on() is not showing up. May I ask the reason and how I could fix it so that the console.log("Testing") will run. Thank you.

Comment: You should include all the code, including with the console.log statement. Also, better to host it on codepen or similar.

Comment: The source code is kind of too long but I will leave all the code below

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source JS code for the client side HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Personalized Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    class ClickableMarker extends mapboxgl.Marker{
        onClick(handleClick){
            this._handleClick = handleClick;
            return this;
        }
        _onMapClick(e){
            const targetElement = e.originalEvent.target;
            const element = this._element;
            if (this._handleClick && (targetElement===element || element.contains((targetElement)))){
                this._handleClick();
            }
        }
    };
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaG9uZ2xlaSIsImEiOiJja251dTZtZjYwZHp4Mm9tbTNlMWFhZ3o4In0.h5SUIBqsfEiHj41z8ajdwg';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [12.550343, 55.665957],
        zoom: 2
    });

    var dep_lat = [];
    var dep_lng = [];
    var arr_lat = [];
    var arr_lng = [];
    var new_markers = [];
    const api_url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/flights";
    async function getapi(url){
        const response = await fetch(url);
        var data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }
    getapi(api_url).then(data => {show(data);});
    function show(data){
        /*
        * This is the only function to manipulate with all airlines
        */
        for (r in data){
            dep_lat.push(data[r]['DepLat']);
            arr_lat.push(data[r]['ArrLat']);
            dep_lng.push(data[r]['DepLng']);
            arr_lng.push(data[r]['ArrLng']);
        }

        /*
        * Load all airlines on the map initially, without the point marker
        */
        map.on('load', function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < dep_lat.length; i++){
                //console.log("init map test");
                map.addSource('route'+String(i),{
                    'type': 'geojson',
                    'data': {
                        'type': 'Feature',
                        'properties': {},
                        'geometry': {
                            'type': 'LineString',
                            'coordinates': [
                                [dep_lng[i],dep_lat[i]],
                                [arr_lng[i],arr_lat[i]]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                });
                map.addLayer({
                    'id': 'route'+String(i),
                    'type': 'line',
                    'source': 'route'+String(i),
                    'layout': {
                        'line-join': 'round',
                        'line-cap': 'round'
                    },
                    'paint': {
                        'line-color': '#C0C',
                        'line-width': 3
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        for (var i = 0; i < dep_lat.length; i++){
            let deplng = dep_lng[i];
            let deplat = dep_lat[i];
            let arrlng = arr_lng[i];
            let arrlat = arr_lat[i];
            new ClickableMarker({color: 'red'})
                .setLngLat([deplng,deplat])
                .onClick(() => {
                    alert(show_route(deplng, deplat));
                })
                .addTo(map);
            new ClickableMarker({color: 'red'})
                .setLngLat([arrlng,arrlat])
                .onClick(() => {
                    alert(show_route(arrlng, arrlat));
                })
                .addTo(map);
        }

        /*
        * End of Function
        */
    }

    /*
    * Other Simple Setup && Test
    */

    function show_route(lng, lat){
        map.on('load',function(){
            console.log("Testing");
        });
        console.log("Testing outside of the map.on();");
        let related_lng = [];
        let related_lat = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < dep_lat.length; i++){
            if(dep_lat[i] === lat && dep_lng[i] === lng){
                related_lat.push(arr_lat[i]);
                related_lng.push(arr_lng[i]);               
            }
            if(arr_lat[i] === lat && arr_lng[i] === lng){
                related_lat.push(dep_lat[i]);
                related_lng.push(dep_lng[i]);
            }            
        }

        var res = `Here are the other ends for  Point(${lng}, ${lat}):`;
        for (var i = 0; i < related_lat.length; i++){
            res += `\n                                               Point(${related_lng[i]}, ${related_lat[i]})`;
        }
        res += "\n";
        return res;
    }

    var marker1 = new ClickableMarker({color: 'yellow'})
            .setLngLat([-10.23,-20.32])
            .onClick(() => {alert("This is nothing!")})
            .addTo(map);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```